# Getting cell position when reading google spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using the google spreadsheet api in php and i'm trying to get all the rows from a given sheet. I manage to read the data but i'd like it to be easier to read. Is there anything like adding the cell letter + number as my array indexes such as

```
A => [
    1 => 'value',
    2 => 'value'
],
B => [
    1 => 'value',
    2 => 'value',
    3 => 'value',
],
```

My code

```
    public function getData($sheetName, $start, $end)
    {
        
        $range = $sheetName.'!'.$start.':'.$end;
        
        $result = $this->SERVICE->spreadsheets_values->get($this->SPREAD_SHEET_ID, $range, ['majorDimension' => 'ROWS']);
        return $result;
    }
```

Thx :)

Comment: Question: lets test values from the [quickstart example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms), what you want to get here is this like array? 
`'A':[ 'Alexandra', 'Andrew', 'Anna' etc...],'B':[ 'Female', 'Male', 'Female' etc...],'C':['4. Senior','1. Freshman','1. Freshman', etc...],etc...` Is it what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd like : 'Line 1' : skipped,  'Line 2':[ 'Alexandra', 'Female', '4. Senior' etc...],'Line 3':[ 'Andrew', 'Male', '1. Freshman' etc...], etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow **[PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)** as it gives you exactly what you want.

If you want to skip the first line just use `$range = 'A2:E';`

## Code snippet:

```php
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';

$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

if (empty($values)) {
    print "No data found.\n";
}else{
    var_dump($values);
}
```

## Output:

```
array(30) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Alexandra"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Female"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "4. Senior"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    [4]=>
    string(7) "English"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Andrew"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "1. Freshman"

etc...
```

## Reference

- [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)